# data json not showing in html

Tags: javascript, json, facebook

i want get json data from my Facebook page , and its a very thing okay , but empty display .

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var dmJSON = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=feed&debug=all&access_token=";
$.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {

      var html = '';

        // loop through all the news items, and append the 
        // title and published date to the html variable.

        for(var i = 0; i < data.feed.length; i++){

            html += '<div>';
            html += data.feed[i].message
            html += '<br>';
            html += data.feed[i].created_time 
            html += '</div>';
        }

        // append all the html variable to the ticker div.
        $("#ticker").append(html);
    });});
```

Comment: nothing wrong with the code. Put a `console.log(data.feed)` and check in console what you are getting from the API

Comment: where ? put console.log(data.feed)

Comment: your description contained an active access token - strongly recommend uninstalling the app from your FB profile immediately to protect your account

Comment: The access token is in the history of the question. It's public now. You'll have to get it revoked to keep it secret.

Comment: add the console.log before the for loop and check in dev console by hitting F12 on any modern browser in Network activity tab

Comment: there no error in console.log

Comment: Maybe you are confused by the name "data" in your `function(data)`. Rename it to, i.e., `function(response)` and use as Quentin say: `response.feed.data`. Your local var `data` is not the same from Facebook response.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the data you are getting. `console.log` the values you are trying to write out. Look at their parent objects when you get `undefined`.

It then rapidly becomes clear that `data.feed` is not an array. It is an object (and doesn't have a `length`).

It has a property called `data` that is an array.

Everywhere you have `data.feed` you should have `data.feed.data`.

Comment: can you please give me full answer

Comment: That is a full answer.

Comment: @aligassan — `console.log` doesn't show errors. It is a function that allows you to examine variables and properties to see what data they contain. It is a very basic tool for debugging that you should learn to use.

Comment: Jesus , now i just want get the data from my page :(

Comment: @aligassan — Well … I spelled out how to do that in very simple terms as well as pointing you in the direction of a basic debugging tool that should allow you to solve this sort of problem without asking for help in the future. What's the problem?